# Can I use Haralick features for OCR of Greek letters?

Tags: image-processing

I have several samples of handwritten images of letters from the Greek alphabet. They are only represent by black pixels on a white background. From everything that I've found on Haralick features, the 'gray-level' is always mentioned. I'm pretty new to image processing, so my question might be a silly one but are the Haralick features irrelevant for simple black/white images?

If they are, could someone provide me with a resource that describes (to a newbie like me) exactly what it is that the Haralick features are computing? Any resources I've found haven't been very helpful in providing a conceptual understanding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work with good appointments  about haralick features

[Co-occurrence matrix and its statistical features as a
new approach for face recognition](http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/elektrik/issues/elk-11-19-1/elk-19-1-8-0906-27.pdf)

Haralick uses the GLCM(Gray level coocurrency matrix) to extract features. 
If you use a binary Image,you will have only 2 gray levels, 2x2 'GLCM', actualy is not a GLCM.

But the haralick features equations are generalized for any number of gray levels.

Comment: Thank you! So what out of the 14 features that he presents (they also can be gotten using the mahotas features module) what would be the best ones to use as inputs for my neural network in the case of OCR? Or is that something that I just have to experiment with?

Comment: I don't know. Never used haralick and NN, but i think that is nice to use. About the features, test all together and try prune few neurons for otimization.